# Permission to restart a single service on Windows Server 2008, 2008R2, 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

I need to be able to grant a user permissions to restart a single service on a Windows server without giving them administrative rights or rights to restart any other services.

I also need them to be able to install a single program via the CMD line but no other programs. I can give them admin access to the folder where the program will be installed but i need to somehow give them permissions to register the DLLs for the service without giving them admin access.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Granting permissions to restart a service is easily possible with SetACL ([example](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/managing-printer-service-and-share-permissions-with-setacl-exe/)). You do not have to log on interactively to restart a service, you can simply use the services management console to connect remotely.

I am not entirely sure, but I think that for installing programs you need to be a member of the group "Administrators".

Comment: This sounds good for the Services I will try it thanks
If anyone has ideas for the installing that would be great. Can you give admin permissions for a command line script to run as an admin without knowing the admin password or the local user having admin access

Comment: What is the difference between your tool SetACL & Subinacl.exe?

Comment: Please post new questions in a new thread.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/239390/setacl-vs-subinacl-exe

Answer (score 0):

While I am not a Windows admin, but rather a developer, this is my suggestion: try setting the "Log on as" to the users account in the Log On tab of the service properties.  This works for me when I want access to a service without administrator privileges, or if I need a service to interact with my account.

Comment: I'd advise against this in a production environment.  When the user's password changes the service will not start and the user can potentially get locked out from too many failed login attempts.

Comment: This may work except that the service already runs under a special account in order to make it work properly.